# Is is okay to move my MBP before it goes to sleep?

Tags: laptop, sleep

Is is okay to move my MBP (or any laptop, for that matter) before the hard drive has stopped spinning and it has fully gone to sleep? Will this do any internal damage?

Comment: Hard drives are far more durable than you think—contrary to common belief, magnets don't do anything to Hard Drives. They're not usually strong enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine so long as it doesn't receive any severe shocks.  Laptop drives are designed to take a certain amount of movement in their stride, and I'm guessing the macbook will probably have g sensors so that it will stop the hard drive spinning if it senses that the device is falling as well. This is common in most reasonably decent laptops.

Comment: So, I can close the lid, then immediately turn it sideways and put in a bag and walk with it?

Comment: Yep,so long as it doesn't get too hot in the bag. It's safest to have it shut down while it's moving but not essential.  The drive is most likely to survive dropping if it's not spinning but the G sensors can normally stop it if you drop it.